# Unrestricted variable name declaration in Mercury

Tags: mercury

I would like to declare a data type in Mercury that can have a variable number of values and names. For instance :

```
type goal ---> pick; give; come.
```

has three variables/values.

I want something like:

```
type myplayer ---> de value declaration here.
```

That's the number of variables are not restricted or fixed.

So I can use myplayer to declare values/variables like `v1, v2, v3 and v4.` The second time I can use it to declare something like: `a, b, c, d, e, z, aa, ab and az`.

The number of the values are not restricted and the names are also not fixed.

I am new in Mercury.

Comment: What do you mean by "the second time"?  Do you mean you want to redefine myplayer, or that you want to use a different subset of its values in a second use?  Also, what is the larger context -- it sounds like you might want a parametric type or typeclass but I'm not sure without context.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, this is simply impossible in Mercury - which is deliberate.

What you might want though, if you want a type that expresses: v1 v2 v3... etc is:

```
:- type my_type
    ----> v(int).

:- func name(my_type) = string.

name(v(Num)) = formst("v%d", [i(Num)]).
```

The type expresses v of all integers, and the function name can be used to 'pretty-print' values of this type.

Answer (score 1):

What you directly ask for, simply cannot be done.  Given

```
:- type question
        --->    truth(string, bool)
        ;       blank(string, string)
        ;       multiple(string, string, list(string)).
```

additional kinds of questions can only be added by extending this type where it is defined, and recompiling the module - and making a lot of other changes, too, as previously deterministic code like

```
answer(truth(_, yes)) = "true".
answer(truth(_, no)) = "false".
answer(blank(_, A)) = A.
answer(multiple(_, A, _)) = A.
```

would fail when given your new question type.  Being told at compile-time where you've failed to update your program to reflect the addition of a "pick-all-the-right-answers" type of question is a good part of the reason you have a question type at all, instead of say lists of strings `[["Are foxes pretty?", "true"], ["Green foxes are ____", "adorable!", "fake", "evidence of animal cruelty"]]` for your question bank.

What you ask for cannot be done.  However, what you actually want to do -- the end to which you thought 'variable numbers of types' would be an helpful means -- can surely be accomplished in some other way.  I can't tell what way that is, as I can't tell why you wanted to do this from your question.  Maybe you'd benefit from reading over [discriminated unions](http://www.mercury.csse.unimelb.edu.au/information/doc-release/mercury_ref/Discriminated-unions.html#Discriminated-unions) or [typeclasses](http://www.mercury.csse.unimelb.edu.au/information/doc-release/mercury_ref/Type-classes.html#Type-classes) in the language reference.

Comment: Not true.  You can declare a specific instantiation of the string type to prevent predicates from failing.  e.g. :- inst foo == bound("x"; "y"; "z").  :- func bar(string::in(foo)) = (int::out) is det.  Granted this is *weird* but it would accomplish what (I think) the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand this question. You want some Prolog-like behavior. I.e without typed predicates. In statically typed system you always can achieve such behavior by handling that by yourself. A lot of time ago I saw such example in Turbo Prolog (they implemented ISO prolog in terms of Turbo/Visual Prolog).

Consider something like (I'm not sure it is correct):

```
:- type any_type ---> atom_value(string)
                 ;    number_value(int)
                 ;    struct_value(any_type, list(any_type)).

guess(atom_value("v1")).
guess(atom_value("a")).
guess(atom_value("aa")).
guess(number_value(42)).
guess(struct_value(atom_value("pair"), [number_value(3), number_value(4)])).
```